# Can we access content page control from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a master page which is used for several content pages.
On every content page there is a user control.
I want to call a method of that control on click of a button which is in the master page.

Is it possible?

Comment: If every content control has the same user control then maybe it should be moved to the master page?

Comment: Add this control to new contentplaceholder in master page and overwrite this in any content page you dont want to show. This is easy to maintain and better option.

Comment: If you are maintaining the click event of button in every control why not add that control also in the User control what is the problem in that.`(UserControl+Button=ContentPage)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to access content page control

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl_Type uc1 = 
    (UserControl_Type)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("UserControlId");
    if (uc1 != null)
    {
        uc1.Method();
    }
}
```

I think you should move UserControl to master page and access usercontrol method in button click in masterpage cs file. You can do following if there are are any content pages you dont want to show this user control

Using content place holders:

In Master Page:
Add:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="UcControlPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<!-- User control here -->
</asp:contentplaceholder>
```

In Content Pages where you **don't** want to show UserControl add following tag and remove this tag from all content pages where you want UserControl to show:

```
<asp:Content ID="UcControlContent1" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="UcControlPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">    
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call method of that control on click of button which is on master page. Can it be possible???

Yes and no. If you're talking client-side then yes, you could invoke a method on a control via JavaScript. If you're talking server-side then no.

---

However, I do have to ask, if the control is available on *every* content page, it's a very good candidate for existing on the **master** page yes? You can hide it if you don't need it in specific content pages.

Comment: Yes but it's too late i have 70 pages which use this master page so it is difficult... how can i do it using javascript???

Comment: @Rupali, I think you misunderstood my point. ***If*** you're trying to execute something client-side, then *yes* you can access it because when client-side it's all one page. ***If*** you're trying to execute something server-side, then just buckle down and make the changes. You will be done in very short order, and probably less time than what it took to manage this question for you.